# Mapinfo SQL - create table that shows where a new polygon does not intersect with another

Tags: sql, mapinfo, overlay, erase

I am attempting to carry out SQL to - create a table that shows where a new polygon (Proposed BMO Overlays) does not intersect with another (Existing BMO Overlays).

I have attached an image on my Map layout to help show the layers involved.
Can you please help?[image]

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier just to use the Erase command to do this.

1. Make a copy of your "Proposed BMO Overlays" table and open the copy into your map
2. Make the "Copy of Proposed BMO Overlays" table editable
3. Right-click on the layer "Copy of Proposed BMO Overlays" table and click on Select all
4. Set the selected objects as target using Set Target on the SPATIAL tab or simply use Ctrl+T
5. Now right-click on the layer "Existing BMO Overlays" and click on Select all.
6. Go to the SPATIAL tab again and click on Erase, Erase Target.

Now the table "Copy of Proposed BMO Overlays" only shows the areas where the proposed BMO Overlays don't intersect or is covered by the Existing BMO Overlays.